# How to clean permanent marker off metal

Tags: cleaning, metals

I have a metal case that I purchased off someone and there are so many permanent marker streaks on it. Is there any way to get them off without damaging the case?

Comment: What is the finish of the case? Can you add a photo?

Comment: More likely a duplicate of "[Permanent marker on a dry erase board?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/17)". Permanent markers and dry-erase markers are quite different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So called "permanent" markers are water insoluble. They are easily removed with most any kind of non-water based solvent such as paint thinner.

Use a slightly damp paper towel to remove a bit at a time. This will probably remove some of the finish on the case as will most of these solvents.

Here are some other things you can use:

1. Liquor such as bourbon (101 proof)
2. Toothpaste (Sprinkle a bit of Baking Soda on it. Mix together.)
3. "Magic Eraser™" (That's the product name.)
4. WD-40
5. Dry-Erase marker (It has a solvent in it.)
6. Pencil eraser (There are different types. Avoid abrasive "ink" types.)
7. Sunscreen cream
8. Nail polish remover

These will not scratch the surface of the metal case if you don't rub too hard.